# How to invoke multiple method signatures within a main method?

Tags: java, methods

So I have three required codes I have already figured out. They are the codes for a quadratic formula, codes for an ISBN checker, and a code for Newtons Method. I'm supposed to make a menu with options 1, 2, and three each containing these codes respectively.

I guess this means I need different methods for this right? I was never really taught - I was told we had to always put in public class void main (String []args){ for everything, and I was just told there were variations to this?

For Quadratics formula, the information is : Return - void and parameters of three doubles, Newtons method: Return - double and parameters of 1 double, and ISBN checker: Return: Boolean and Parameters of 1 string. I don't really understand the parameters thing either. Help would be appreciated. I know this aesthetically looks horrible, but because my codes for now are relatively short I just edit the style when I' done. I know a lot of things are wrong in this too and I've spent time trying to figure them out.

```
import Java.util.Scanner;

public class HelperMethod{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("You have three options. press one for the quadratic Formula, 2 for the newtons Method, and 3 for an ISBN checker.");
        int input = userInputScanner.nextInt();

        if (input = 1){

        }else if (input = 2) {
            private class NewtonsMethod {

            public static void NewtonsMethod(String[] args) {   
                Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                double guess, fX, fPrimeX, newGuess;

                System.out.println ("enter in a value give"); 
                guess = userInputScanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.println ("Your guess is " + guess);

                while (true) {
                    fX = (6 * Math.pow (guess,4)) - (13 * Math.pow (guess,3)) - (18 * Math.pow (guess,2)) + (7 * guess) + 6;
                    fPrimeX = (24 * Math.pow (guess,3)) - (39 * Math.pow (guess,2)) - 36 * guess + 7;
                    newGuess = guess - (fX / fPrimeX);
                    System.out.println ("A possible root is " + newGuess);
                    if (Math.abs(newGuess - guess) < 0.00001) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        guess = newGuess;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println ("The root is: " + newGuess);
            }
        }
    }else{
        private class BookNumber {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                char f;
                int e, g, h;
                int result = 0;

                System.out.println ("Pleas enter a thirteen digit number");
                String a = scanner.nextLine();

                if (a.length() == 13){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i ++) {
                        f = a.charAt(i);
                        e = Character.digit(f, 10); 
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            g = e * 1;
                            result = result + g;
                        } else {
                            g = e * 3;
                            result = result + g;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println ("The added sum of you numbers is " + result);
                    if (result % 10 == 0) {
                        System.out.println ("This combination IS a ISBN number");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println ("This is NOT an ISBN number");
                    } 
                } else {
                    System.out.println ("This combination is not thirteen digits long");
                }
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, right now you're setting input to 1 in your first if statement. To compare input to 1 instead, use the `==` operator, i.e. `if (input == 1) {...`. Secondly, you don't really need to use classes, you can simply have methods `NewtonsMethod()`, `BookNumber()` etc. and run them when the input is correct.

```
public class HelperMethod{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input;

        //Handle user input

        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                newtonsMethod();
                break;
            case 2:
                bookNumber();
                break;
            case 3: 
                anotherMethod();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void newtonsMethod() {
        //Your code
    }

    public static void bookNumber() {
        //Your code
    }

    public static void anotherMethod() {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: In java methods and non static variables are named adhering to camel case starting with a lower case letter.

Comment: You are of course correct, I've just copied the class names of the original question and forgot to change them, thank you. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help - but can I put all the methods in their respective cases instead of putting them after?

Comment: No problem. On a side note and since you are new to Stackoverflow, please see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). To answer your question: You can, please see [Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Methods should never be inside one another. That is what classes are for. A method is an element within a class. For example, in your case your class was named "HelperMethod". Your methods need to begin after the main method's code block is closed with a curly brace "}"

as an example

```
// This would be your main method.
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Your method is CALLED here.
    someMethod();
{

// Then this is where your next method would start.
public static void someMethod() {
    // Your code for the method of course goes here.
}
```

Of course you need your class setup and needed imports ABOVE the main method but you have that setup correctly already. With this setup, it makes it easy to call public methods that are in other classes. Your private methods are not really needed unless you intend to use more than one class, at which point you will need to import that class and then call the method like so

```
SomeClass.someMethod();
```